# What should I use triggers or constraints?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, constraints

In sql Developer I created a table

```
Bill (id,nr,cost,days,total -all integers)
```

and I need to create a constraint (or trigger -what is best) to act like

```
IF nr > 10 then total = total -5 (total = nr * cost * days ).


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER discount 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Bill 
UPDATE Bill  
    set total = nr * cost * nr - 5;
WHEN (nr_slide > 10 )
```

Can I use update inside triggers?

Comment: A constraint won't help you, and a trigger is not required. Instead, use a view (as per Ash's answer) or a generated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraint can only prevent putting wrong value to table. If you use constraint, you need to calculate correct value for total and insert into table, otherwise no rows will be inserted. It means that you need a trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER discount 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON Bill 
for each row -- I added it here
begin
  IF :new.nr > 10 then 
     :new.total = :new.nr * :new.cost * :new.days - 5;
  END IF;
end;
```

If this is an educational project - no problem (of course, it is a problem - it is a quite bad example for education). In applications for real life use advise of Ash Burlaczenko.

Comment: I get this error                                             Virtual column cannot be updated in trigger body
54029. 0000 -  "Virtual column cannot be updated in trigger body"
*Cause:    Attempted to change the value of virtual column in a trigger body"
*Action:   This is not valid, change the trigger definition.

Comment: @AdiMuntean This radically changes the situation! If you use virtual columns, you, first, should mention it in question, and second, use this expression in table's DDL.

Comment: -and still ,how can I use it in the table's DDL? That was the request : "The create a table that has those columns and the total column is calculated based on nr,days,and cost .I created table like this : CREATE TABLE BILL ( ... total AS (nr * cost * days ));

Answer (score 1):

I'd say neither, your table shouldn't have a `Total` column. Instead you should have a view which selects from `Bill` and calculates the `Total`. Something like

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    nr, 
    days, 
    CASE WHEN nr > 10 THEN 
        (nr * cost * days) - 5 
    ELSE 
        (nr * cost * days) 
    END AS 'Total'
FROM view_Bill
```

Comment: That is the request on my project.To add the total column and then add a constraint/trigger to act like that